# How to write database-agnostic functions to make them easier to unit-test

Tags: database, unit-testing, go

**TLDR**: What's the best way of unit-testing a function that uses a database as its datasource but that the datasource does not have to be a database (that is, the function isn't aware of where the data is coming from. e.g. it can be an object, etc.)?

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

I'm trying to find out what's the best practice for unit-testing functions that use a database as its datasource - which is passed through its parameter - but that the datasource does not have to be a database (e.g. it can be an object, etc.). The reason I add the clause, "that the datasource does not have to be a database," is because I don't want to use a database during unit-tests. So, how do I write a function that is database-agnostic?

One possible approach is to provide an "env" parameter that holds the datasource, like so:

```
type Env struct {
    DataSource  interface{}
}

func FunctionToTest(env Env) {
    switch et := (env.DataSource).(type) {
    case UserDatasource:
        userSource := (env.DataSource).(UserDatasource)
        user := userSource.getUser()
    default:
        // Throw error
    }
}

func FunctionToTest2(env Env) {
    switch et := (env.DataSource).(type) {
    case CredentialsDatasource:
        credentialSource := (env.DataSource).(CredentialsDatasource)
        password := credentialSource.getPassword()
    default:
        // Throw error
    }
}
```

The issue with this is that it seems "hacky" and it feels like there exists a better solution. The reason I want to learn how to do this is so that I can write unit-tests that mock the database.

I appreciate any and all input.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps the function should receive a supplier function as its argument. That is, a function that has no arguments and returns the required resource type, such as a user or credential.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would want to use an interface here. A common pattern used to abstract away where the data comes from is the repository pattern. [Here](http://manuel.kiessling.net/2012/09/28/applying-the-clean-architecture-to-go-applications/) is an article where you can read about the repository pattern and other tips for developing well-written Go applications.

```
package user

type User struct {
    ID int64
    Name string
}

type Repository interface {
    Find(id int64) (*User, error)
    Store(u *User) error
}

func ChangeUserName(id int64, name string, r Repository) error {
    u, err := r.Find(id)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    u.Name = name
    err = r.Store(u)
    return err
}
```

Now you are able to pass in any struct with the methods matching your `user.Repository` interface. For example:

```
package mysql

type DB struct {
    *sql.DB
}

func New(db *sql.DB) *DB {
    return DB{db}
}

func (d *DB) Find(id int64) (*user.User, error) {
    // mysql stuff to find user
}

func (d *DB) Store(u *user.User) error {
    // mysql stuff to store user
}
```

then ...

```
package main

func main() {
    // ...
    // conn := code to open *sql.DB connection
    db := mysql.New(conn)
    err := user.ChangeUserName(1, 'bob', db)
    // ...
}
```

You can now also use a mock to test your function.

```
package mocks

type UserRepository struct {
    Users []*user.User
    ShouldError bool
}

func (r *UserRepository) Find(id int64) (*user.User, error) {
    if r.ShouldError {
        return nil, errors.New("")
    }
    for _, u := range r.Users {
        if u.ID == id {
            return u
        }
    }
    return errors.New("user not found")
}

func (r *UserRepository) Store(u *user.User) error {
    if r.ShouldError {
        return errors.New("")
    }
    r.Users = append(r.Users, u)
    return nil
}
```

then to test...

```
func Test_ChangeUserName_Stores_Changed_User(t *testing.T) {
    u := &user.User{ID: 1, Name: 'Bob'}
    r := mocks.UserRepository{Users: []*user.User{u}}
    err := user.ChangeUserName(1, 'Fred', r)
    // ...
}
```